# Pra que serve `$.extend` e `$.fn.extend`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

O jQuery possui as funções `$.extend` e `$.fn.extend`.

- Pra quê elas servem?
- Como usá-las?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função do [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) é copiar propriedades de um ou mais objetos para um objeto de destino. Ou seja, é uma função utilitária, que atua sobre objetos "normais", nada específico do jQuery.

```
var a = { foo:10 };
var b = { bar:20 };
$.extends(a, b);
// a agora possui { foo:10, bar:20 }
```

Um dos seus usos mais comuns é para se clonar um objeto. Para isso, basta usar um novo objeto (vazio) como primeiro argumento:

```
var a = { foo:10, bar:[20, 30, 40] };
var b = $.extend({}, a); // Cópia rasa (shallow copy)

a.bar[1] = 50;
console.log(b.bar[1]); // 50
```

Ou, para se conseguir uma "cópia profunda" (*deep copy*), passando-se `true` como primeiro argumento:

```
var a = { foo:10, bar:[20, 30, 40] };
var b = $.extend(true, {}, a); // Cópia profunda (deep copy)

a.bar[1] = 50;
console.log(b.bar[1]); // 30
```

Outra possibilidade é se criar um objeto que é um conjunto de vários outros. Isso pode ser usado, por exemplo, para se implementar [*mixins*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27179/215):

```
var classeA = { ... }; // Uma "classe" no caso é somente um conjunto de propriedades
var classeB = { ... }; // e métodos relacionados. Poderia-se "herdar" dessa classe
var classeC = { ... }; // usando-a como protótipo, mas como herdar de várias?

var mixin = $.extend({}, classeA, classeB, classeC);
```

Como regra geral, o primeiro objeto passado como argumento é modificado, e os demais apenas contribuem propriedades a ele. Se houver um `true` no início, a cópia é profunda, caso contrário ela é rasa.

E quanto ao [`$.fn.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/)? Isso é somente um "atalho" para se adicionar novas propriedades ao próprio `$.fn`:

```
$.fn.extend({ ... }, { ... }, ...);
// É equivalente a:
$.extend($.fn, { ... }, { ... }, ...);
```

(E pra quem não sabe, `$.fn` é onde ficam definidas as funções que se aplicam a qualquer objeto jQuery. Ex.: `$(seletor).foo(10, 20)` implica que existe uma função `foo` em `$.fn`.)

Answer (score 3):

O `$.extend` serve para "fundir" dois ou mais objetos no primeiro
Ex: (retirado de http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ )

```
  var object1 = {
      maça: 0,
      banana: { peso: 52, preço: 100 },
      cereja: 97
    };
    var object2 = {
      banana: { preço: 200 },
      laranja: 100
    };

  $.extend( object1, object2 );
```

Ao imprimir o objeto 1 tem-se:

```
{"maça"0, "banana":{preço:200}, cereja:97, laranja:100}
```

Nesse caso o objeto 1 (que contém maça, banana e cereja) é fundido com o objeto 2 (que contem banana e laranja). Perceba que ao fundir os objetos a banana é susbstituida (antes possuia preço e peso agora só possui preço) e a nova propriedade (laranja) é adicionada.