# Como criar um objeto com duas ou mais instâncias em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Em JavaScript sei que é possível criar uma instância de uma classe usando `'new'`

```
new Classe
```

E como criar um objeto que seja instância de várias classes? Por exemplo

```
new Classe, OutraClasse...
```

Eu creio que isso pode ser possível porque isso alerta `true`:

```
var el = document.createElement('a');
alert(el instanceof HTMLElement && el instanceof HTMLAnchorElement);
```

Além disso, `el` tem mais que 2 instâncias...

Comment: O texto da pergunta está confuso. Acredito que você queira saber se é possível criar um objeto que seja instãncia de 2 classes. Estritamete falando isso é possível, desde que uma das classes seja derivada da outra, como é o caso de HTMLAnchorElement e HTMLElement. Mas no caso geral isso náo é possível em programação orientada a objetos, um objeto é sempre instância de UMA única classe.

Comment: @JoséX. Classe derivada da outra? Como eu poderia derivar uma classe da outra?

Comment: veja resposta do @Sergio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repara no seguinte exemplo:

```js
class Animal {
    mostrarNome() {
        console.log('Eu sou um animal qualquer...');
    }
}

class Humano extends Animal {
    mostrarNome() {
        console.log('Eu sou um ser humano...');
    }
}

class Pessoa extends Humano {
    constructor(nome) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    mostrarNome() {
        console.log('Eu sou um ser humano... de nome ' + this.nome);
    }
}

var vaca = new Animal();
var sergio = new Pessoa('Sérgio');
vaca.mostrarNome(); // Eu sou um animal qualquer...
sergio.mostrarNome(); // Eu sou um ser humano... de nome Sérgio

console.log(vaca instanceof Animal, vaca instanceof Humano, vaca instanceof Pessoa); // true false false
console.log(sergio instanceof Animal, sergio instanceof Humano, sergio instanceof Pessoa); // true, true, true
```

O que se passa aqui é que tens classes que herdam de outras. Todas as classes que são descendentes de outras dão sempre `true` quando verificas se são uma instância da original. A isto chama-se herança e o que acontece é que a classe de onde se herda fica escrita no *prototype* da nova classe. Há respostas bem completas sobre isso, como o @Maniero indicou.

Criei este exemplo para perceberes que é possivel o que queres. Simplesmente usando `extends` na sintaxe ES2015, ou copiando o prototype à mão com:

```
var NovaClasse = Object.create(ClasseAntiga);
```

Answer (score 2):

Só existe uma instância criada. Uma instância pode ter mais de um tipo, desde que exista hierarquia entre eles. Então `el` é do tipo `HTMLAnchorElement` que por sua vez foi herdado de `HTMLElement`, portando este objeto satifaz pelo menos esses dois tipos, afinal tudo o que existe na "classe" base está disponível na "classe" derivada.

Note que o normal em JavaScript é usar protótipos e não classes. veja mais em [Existe classe em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108548/101), [JavaScript é uma linguagem Orientada a Objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141645/101) e [O que é Protótipo Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/101).