# Existe alguma diferença relevante entre "Programação orientada a objetos" e "Programação orientada a classes"?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, independente-de-linguagem

Estava lendo um *post* que o membro @Maniero indicou, e me deparei com uma resposta de um outro membro que me gerou mais dúvidas e resolvi pesquisar.

Na resposta estava a seguinte frase: "Programação orientada a objetos" e "programação orientada a classes", porém, fiz algumas pesquisas 
e não encontrei conteúdo relevante para esclarecer essa dúvida.

Link da resposta acima onde extrai o texto: [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100812/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-uma-classe-e-um-objeto)

Link de pesquisa: https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Orientada_a_Objetos/Classes_e_Objetos

No Wikilivros, não ficou clara a explicação sobre o que é "Programação orientada a objetos" e o que é "Programação orientada a classes" .

Cada vez que procuro mais informação através de pesquisa, não sei definir qual seria mais relevante para o meu caso.

Alguém tem uma explicação melhor para contribuir?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programação orientada a classes é um subtipo de programação orientada a objetos.

As linguagens que permitem o uso de programação orientada a objetos mais populares, como Java e C#, obrigam o desenvolvedor a definir seu código em classes. Isso estimula a compartimentalização do código e tem diversos benefícios que já foram discutidos exaustivamente em outras perguntas.

No entanto, o uso forçado de classes também traz limitações, que outras linguagens orientadas a objetos não têm. Um exemplo é Javascript. Essa linguagem é orientada a objetos, e orientada a protótipos - que são diferentes de classes. O conceito de classe nem existe em Javascript. Os comportamentos são herdados entre objetos, não entre tipos. Assim como o uso de classes, o uso de protótipos tem lá suas vantagens e limitações. Mas acredito que a análise comparativa é um tema para outra pergunta.

Mais detalhes sobre protótipos em [O que é Protótipo Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42962/o-que-%C3%A9-prot%C3%B3tipo-javascript)