# Quando utilizar o termo "prototype" para se referir a um método em JavaScript, como em "Array.prototype.forEach"?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, convenções-de-nome

O JavaScript possui diversos objetos com métodos, como é o caso de *arrays* que têm, por exemplo, o método [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Mas eventualmente um mesmo nome pode ser utilizado por outros objetos, como [método `forEach` do `NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). Em casos como esse, a distinção é necessária para que se especifique o construtor (`Array` e `NodeList`, por exemplo) em alguma parte do "nome completo".

Então, do ponto de vista semântico da linguagem, qual a forma correta para se utilizar esse "nome completo"?

- `Array.prototype.forEach`?
- `Array.forEach`?

Se forem diferentes, há uma situação correta para utilizar cada uma dessas situações? Ou os dois são "equivalentes" e se referem à mesma coisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Nesta resposta, usarei os exemplos `Array.prototype.forEach` e `Array.from` (não usei <s>`Array.forEach`</s> porque este não existe). No entanto, o mesmo vale para qualquer outra função construtora (além de `Array`) ou outra propriedade (além de `forEach`).</sub>

---

### TL; DR

- `<constructor>.prototype.<method>` deve ser utilizado para fazer referência aos "métodos de instância". Por exemplo, `Array.prototype.forEach`.
- `<constructor>.<method>` deve ser utilizado para fazer referência aos "métodos estáticos". Por exemplo, `Array.from`.

São diferentes.

---

Em JavaScript, toda função possui uma propriedade chamada `prototype`, que é sempre um objeto (ou `null`). No caso da função `Array`, a propriedade `prototype` é um objeto que contém diversas propriedades e métodos, como `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, etc. Parece familiar, certo?

Quando uma função pode ser invocada utilizando o operador `new`, ela também pode ser chamada de função construtora. Assim, quando um novo objeto é criado **a partir** de uma função construtora, a propriedade interna `[[Prototype]]` desse novo objeto criado aponta para a propriedade `prototype` da função construtora.

Por exemplo, como `Array` é uma funcão construtora, posso construir um novo objeto array assim:

```
const arr = new Array();
// `arr.[[Prototype]]` aponta para `Array.prototype`

// Podemos então, acessar, a partir do objeto construído,
// os métodos da propriedade `prototype` da função construtora,
// isto é, `arr.[[Prototype]]` aponta para `Array.prototype`.
typeof arr.map; // 'function'
typeof arr.filter; // 'function'
typeof arr.reduce; // 'function'
```

Assim, graças a cadeia de protótipos, todos os métodos de `Array.prototype` estarão disponíveis em `arr`. Para entender melhor, leia as respostas de [Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15247/69296) e de [O que é Protótipo Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/69296).

Podemos concluir, então, que:

- ### `Array.prototype.forEach`

  É a nomenclatura a ser usada para fazer referência a um método (nesse caso `forEach`) disponível na propriedade `prototype` de uma função construtora (como `Array`). Em face da cadeia de protótipos do JavaScript, o método `forEach` poderá ser acessado como propriedade de qualquer objeto construído a partir da função consttutora `Array`.

  Em outras palavras, podemos utilizar uma nomenclatura como `Array.prototype.forEach` para fazer referência aos métodos disponíveis nas "instâncias" de `Array`.
- ### `Array.from`

  É a nomenclatura a ser usada para fazer referência a uma propriedade da função construtora `Array`. Como não faz parte de `Array.prototype`, não é passado às "instâncias" de `Array`. Pode-se dizer que é a nomenclatura a ser usada por "métodos estáticos".

---

Alguns exemplos:

```js
// `arr` é como se fosse uma "instância" de `Array`:
const arr = new Array();

console.log(typeof Array.map); // 'undefined'
console.log(typeof Array.from); // 'function'

console.log('---');

console.log(typeof Array.prototype.map); // 'function'
console.log(typeof Array.prototype.from); // 'undefined'

console.log('---');

console.log(typeof arr.map); // 'function'
console.log(typeof arr.from); // 'undefined'
```

Note, no exemplo acima, que, *se não modificado*, `arr` "herdará" todas as propriedades de `Array.prototype`. O porquê disso foi no começo desta resposta.

Observe também que, embora disponível como propriedade da função construtora `Array`, o "método estático" `Array.from` *não* é acessível a partir de `Array.prototype` ou de `arr` (a "instância").

Saiba também que (para o exemplo acima):

- `arr.forEach` é o mesmo que `Array.prototype.forEach`;
- `[].forEach` é o mesmo que `Array.prototype.forEach`;

No entanto, é mais conveniente utilizar `Array.prototype.forEach` do que `arr.forEach`, já que este último depende do nome da variável (nesse caso, `arr`).

`[].forEach` também é válido, mas somente porque `[]` é uma forma literal do JavaScript que sempre irá se referir a um objeto array construído a partir de `Array`.

Em suma, o padrão `<constructor>.prototype.<method>` é sempre garantido para fazer referência aos métodos presentes em objetos construídos a partir de `<constructor>`.

Answer (score 0):

Elas são diferentes.
`Array.prototype.forEach` te permite acessar a função construtora do `Array.forEach`.

```
console.log(Array.forEach) // undefined
console.log(Array.prototype.forEach) // function forEach() { [native code] }
```

Desta forma você pode até mesmo modificar o comportamento do `forEach`.

```js
let lista = ["Um", "dois"]

const inverter = function () {
  return lista.reverse()
}

// Aqui acesso o protótipo do forEach
Array.prototype.forEach = inverter


console.log(lista) // ["Um","dois"]
console.log(lista.forEach()) // ["dois", "Um"]
```

Em resumo você usa `Array.forEach` quando quer acessar o objeto e `Array.prototype.forEach` para o protótipo do objeto.

Comment: Como assim, “função construtora do `forEach`”?

Comment: Eu separei duas coisas para a resposta da sua pergunta, https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Prototype e https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor... No JS eu acredito que a maioria das funções nativas, quando você encontra ´[native code]´ em um retorno, ela é uma classe... Outra questão é que o @Thyago Dias lhe mostrou um exemplo pois não é recomendado mudar funções nativas pelo motivo de gerar erros internos a não ser que saiba o que está fazendo.

Comment: Thyago, eu ainda não consegui compreender o que você quis dizer com "[...] função construtora do `Array.forEach`". Poderia tentar esclarecer, por favor?

Comment: Um construtor nada mais é do que uma função, ou seja, função construtora é uma estrutura que descreve estados e comportamentos de um objeto. Uma classe pode ser considerada uma função construtora