# Qual o equivalente da função dir do Python em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos, protótipo

Eu estava procurando por uma função em javascript equivalente à função `dir` do Python. Em Python, se quero ver todos os métodos associados a determinado objeto, basta passar a função `dir` diretamente ao `constructor` do objeto ou a uma instância do objeto. Assim, para ver métodos associados a strings, por exemplo, faço:

```
print(dir(str))
```

Ou:

```
print(dir("stack"))
```

Em JavaScript, eu descobri o método `getOwnPropertyNames`. Contudo, quando usei esse método tive acesso ao que parece ser apenas uma parcela dos métodos do objeto em questão. Exemplo:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array))
```

Retorna:

```
[ 'length', 'name', 'prototype', 'isArray', 'from', 'of' ]
```

Ocorre que `Arrays` em Javascript também tem o método `sort()`:

```
var names = ['Jesse', 'Walter', 'Hank']
console.log(names.sort())
```

Que resulta:

```
[ 'Hank', 'Jesse', 'Walter' ]
```

Porque o `sort` não apareceu na lista de métodos de `Array` quando utilizei `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`? Existe uma função em JavaScript equivalente ao `dir` do Python que retorna a lista completa de métodos de um objeto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso acontece porque, na verdade, métodos como o `sort` não pertencem ao construtor `Array`, mas sim ao `Array.prototype`.

Note, na saída do código que você rodou, que o `Array` possui uma propriedade chamada `prototype`. É nela que estão todos os métodos e propriedades que poderão ser acessados em qualquer instância de `Array`.

Então, para listar todos os métodos das *instâncias* de um `Array`, faça:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype));
```

No JavaScript, quando você instancia um objeto a partir de um construtor, o objeto `<constructor>.prototype` será associado ao  protótipo do objeto construído. Isso é explicado em mais detalhes em [Como funciona a cadeia de protótipos em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/69296). A questão da nomenclatura é explicada em mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/480790/69296).

Pense nas propriedades de `Array` como "métodos estáticos" e nas propriedades de `Array.prototype` como "métodos de instância".

Vale notar que a sintaxe de *array* literal é, basicamente, açúcar sintático para `new Array()`. Portanto, os dois jeitos de se criar um *array* abaixo são equivalentes:

```
const arr1 = new Array();
const arr2 = [];
```

---

Note que você não pode utilizar a função `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` diretamente em uma instância para tentar acessar seus métodos "herdados", já que, como o próprio nome da função diz, somente as "*own properties*", isto é, as propriedades definidas no próprio objeto serão retornadas. Como propriedades como `sort` e `forEach` não foram definidas *diretamente* em *cada* instância, mas sim em seu protótipo, você não terá acesso a elas.

Você pode utilizar a função `Reflect.getPrototypeOf` para acessar o protótipo de qualquer objeto, que, teoricamente, não pode ser acessado "diretamente":

```js
console.log(
  // Retorna as propriedades do protótipo de `[]` (uma instância de `Array`)
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(
    // Acessa o protótipo do 1º argumento. No caso, `[]`.
    Reflect.getPrototypeOf([])
  )
);
```

<sup>Utilizei o termo "teoricamente" acima porque, pela especificação, o protótipo de um objeto é uma "propriedade interna da linguagem". No entanto, existem meios para o acessar, tais como a propriedade `__proto__` e as funções `Object.getPrototypeOf` e `Reflect.getPrototypeOf`.</sup>

Quando você dá um `console.dir` em algum objeto (como uma instância de `Array` — `[]`), a propriedade `__proto__` que aparece lá é uma referência ao protótipo do objeto. É esse *protótipo* (que não é "acessível" diretamente, conforme já vimos acima) que contém os métodos (como `sort` ou `forEach`) que você usa.

É um pouco confuso. Não deixe de compreender [o que é protótipo em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/69296) (algo essencial para entender esta resposta). Esta [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/69296) também é excelente. Além disso, não deixe de saber como a [nomenclatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/480790/69296) funciona para não escrever errado (`Array.prototype.forEach` é diferente de <s>`Array.forEach`</s>).

---

Se você realmente quiser listar todas as propriedades (incluindo não enumeráveis, símbolos e "herdadas" via herança prototípica), pode fazer sua própria função `dir`. Assim:

```
function dir(obj) {
  const allKeys = new Set();
  let currProto = Object(obj);

  while (currProto) {
    for (const key of Reflect.ownKeys(currProto)) {
      allKeys.add(key);
    }

    currProto = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(currProto);
  }

  // Retorna em formato de array por conveniência.
  return [...allKeys];
}
```

O código basicamente percorre toda a cadeia de protótipos do valor fornecido, inserindo no *set* todas as propriedades que ele encontrar. Utilizei o `Set` porque ele evita elementos duplicados (o que pode ocorrer).

Havendo propriedades duplicadas, a mais "próxima" será retornada — esse comportamento se deve ao modelo prototípico do JavaScript. Saiba mais sobre o [`Reflect.ownKeys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys).

Exemplo de uso:

```js
function dir(obj) {
  const allKeys = new Set();
  let currProto = Object(obj);

  while (currProto) {
    for (const key of Reflect.ownKeys(currProto)) {
      allKeys.add(key);
    }

    currProto = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(currProto);
  }

  return [...allKeys];
}

const myArr = [1, 2, 3];
const allKeys = dir(myArr);

console.log(allKeys.includes('0')); //=> true; índice 0 (é uma propriedade, já que arrays nada mais são que objetos)
console.log(allKeys.includes('map')); //=> true; herdada via herança prototípica
console.log(allKeys.includes('from')); //=> false; é método "estático" de array. Logo, não existe na instância

console.log(allKeys);
```

<sup><sup>Os `null` que apareceram no último `console.log` do exemplo acima são as propriedades com chave simbólica (tipo `symbol`). O console do *snippet* do Stack Overflow não sabe mostrar símbolos corretamente, o que justifica a impressão de `null`.</sup></sup>