# Oque é Cross-Cutting e qual sua relação com Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP)?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, ddd, orientação-a-aspectos

Oque é Cross-Cutting e qual sua relação com Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP)? E em uma arquitetura DDD qual sua função?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Muitos aspectos de um sistema são projetados de forma **hierárquica** e/ou em **camadas**. Isso parte do princípio que nem todo componente do sistema precisa interagir com todo outro componente, e a organização dos componentes é feita em grupos coesos com a função de cumprir uma responsabilidade bem específica.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em geral os componentes que cumprem determinada responsabilidade pertencem apenas a uma única camada e/ou ocupam uma única posição na hierarquia de classes. Entretanto, há certos aspectos que dizem respeito a mais de uma camada, não podendo ser isolados em um componente específico sem relação direta com todos os outros. Diz-se então que esse aspecto "cruza" ou "corta" a hierarquia, ou em inglês que é ***cross-cutting*** ("transversal").

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muitas vezes os aspectos considerados *cross-cutting* (a Wikipedia tem [uma lista](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) com alguns deles) são tratados de maneira *ad-hoc*, por exemplo espalhando-se por todo o código chamadas não relacionadas com a função primária do mesmo:

```java
void calcularImposto() {
    log("Iniciando o cálculo");
    if ( numeroPeriodos == 0 ) {
        log("Número de períodos igual a zero", Logging.ERROR);
        throw new StateException("Número de períodos igual a zero");
    }
    ...
    log("Cálculo efetuado com sucesso");
}
```

A Programação Orientada por Aspectos, por outro lado, busca *centralizar* cada aspecto, organizar o código que lida com o mesmo em um conjunto à parte, e então **injetar** esse código ao longo de todo o projeto, independentemente da camada original e/ou hierarquia de classes. Dessa forma o código original fica limpo e focado na sua responsabilidade.

(Nota: o exemplo abaixo, em AspectJ, é bastante simplificado, e não sei se reflete as práticas atuais. Estudei AOP há muitos anos - antes mesmo de Java dar suporte a *annotations* - e não toco no assunto desde então.)

Na classe principal:

```java
void calcularImposto() {
    if ( numeroPeriodos == 0 )
        throw new StateException("Número de períodos igual a zero");
    ...
}
```

No "aspecto":

```java
@Aspect
public class MethodLogger {
  @Around("execution(* calcular*(..))")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) {
    log("Iniciando o cálculo");
    try {
        Object result = point.proceed();
        log("Cálculo efetuado com sucesso");
        return result;
    } catch(StateException e) {
        log("Número de períodos igual a zero", Logging.ERROR);
        throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>[Fonte](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html)</sup>

Aqui temos um exemplo de **injeção de dependência** - o código original não "tem ciência" de que nenhum registro está sendo feito, ele simplesmente cumpre sua função e pronto! O aspecto em si - quando habilitado (e pelo que me recordo é possível habilitar/desabilitar aspectos ao menos em tempo de compilação ou carga) - é quem injeta seu código nos pontos específicos necessários para cumprir sua função. A relação de dependência entre as camadas continua simples e é respeitada pelos seus membros, somente o aspecto *cross-cutting* precisa fazer referência a todos os outros (não necessariamente de forma fortemente acoplada como nesse exemplo).

A propósito, AOP não é estritamente necessária para tratar bem de aspectos *cross-cutting* - algumas linguagens, como Python, fazem uso extensivo de [**decoradores**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator) para isolar os aspectos não pertencentes à responsabilidade da camada. A principal diferença é que isso precisa ser feito explicitamente, não há inversão de controle:

```python
def logado(fn):
    def ret(*args, **kwargs):
        log("Iniciando o cálculo")
        try:
            resultado = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            log("Cálculo efetuado com sucesso")
            return resultado
        except:
            log("Número de períodos igual a zero", Logging.ERROR)
            raise
    return ret

@logado
def calcular_imposto():
    ...
```

Outra maneira de lidar com o problema é através do uso de [*mixins*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27179/215) (i.e. código "herdado" por classes de diferentes hierarquias, sem que tenham necessariamente relação alguma uma com a outra).

Enfim, a definição de *cross-cutting* é essa, mas pra saber se um aspecto é *cross-cutting* ou não isso vai depender de qual é a sua arquitetura. Se sua hierarquia for de um jeito, determinado aspecto pode ter mais facilidade de "se encaixar", se ela for de outro, não. Seja como for, sempre haverá casos em que determinada funcionalidade "atravessa" várias camadas e/ou afeta classes de diferentes hierarquias, e esses casos demandarão *alguma* forma de tratamento, seja "desorganizado" (espalhando código relacionado [entre si] por todo o sistema), ou "organizado", através de uma das técnicas descritas acima ou outra similar.

Comment: Então pode-se concluir que **AOP** é uma maneira de se implementar recursos **crosscutting**. E quanto ao **DDD**? Apenas para não deixar essa parte da pergunta de fora, eu diria que não há nenhuma relação em particular, e que numa arqutetura DDD recursos crosscutting podem ser necessários ou não, tanto quanto em qualquer outra arquitetura; e que AOP pode ou não ser usada na arquitetura DDD também tanto quanto em qualquer outra (os fatores de decisão são outros: está disponível? é útil? simplifica?...).

Answer (score 17):

> E em uma arquitetura DDD qual sua função?

Em uma arquitetura DDD, Eric Evans em seu livro de 2004 intitulado:
Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software nos diz que a função da Infrastructure Layer é:

> Fornecer recursos técnicos genéricos que suportam as camadas mais altas:
>   envio de mensagem para a aplicação, persistência para o domínio,
>   desenho de widgets para a interface do usuário, etc. A camada de infra-estrutura pode também
>   suportar o padrão de interacções entre as quatro camadas através de uma
>   estrutura arquitetônica.

e é exatamente aí onde o Cross-Cutting entra em ação:

por exemplo, além de você possuir seu projeto Data com seus repositórios, você irá ter um projeto também do tipo Cross-Cutting dentro de sua infrastructure layer responsável por:

> Suportar o padrão de interacções entre as quatro camadas através de uma
>   estrutura arquitetônica.

Como por exemplo Inversion Of Control.

Sua aplicação, seu repositório, sua própria infraestrutura, e seus serviços, utilizam ou podem utilizar uma framework de IoC, e isso é responsabilidade da Infratructure, Cross-Cutting.

Há outros exemplos também, como por exemplo logging do sistema, outra responsabilidade da cross-cutting na arquitetura DDD.

---

> qual sua relação com Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP)?

Simples, o cross-cutting é um conceito podendo ser usado em qualquer arquitetura, no caso da AOP, ele segue praticamente a mesma filosofia do DDD, no AOP, você separa as responsabilidades de acordo com os aspectos, e um dos aspectos é exatamente a parte do "código" onde você identifica que será usado em toda a arquitetura como exemplo o próprio IoC(Inversion Of Control), logo sendo um forte candidato a fazer parte do projeto de Cross-Cutting