# Padrão para a utilização de logs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ddd, log

Tenho um projeto organizado da seguinte forma:

```
1. Web (ASP.NET MVC)
2. Application
3. Domain
4. Infra.Data
5. Infra.Log (NLog)
6. Infra.IoC
```

As referências dos projetos estão da seguinte forma:

```
- Web --> Application
- Web --> Domain
- Application --> Domain
- Infra.Data --> Domain
- Infra.Log --> Application
- Web --> Infra.IoC
```

Criei uma interface de log na camada de Application e a sua implementação na camada Infra.Log. E, através de injeção
de dependência, eu a utilizo na camada Web e Application.
Porém não da para utilizar o serviço nas outras camadas
devido a referência entre os projetos.

Não quero "sujar" os projetos com referências desnecessárias,
pois o DDD recomenda uma certa ordem nas referências.
Por exemplo, a camada de Infra.Data não pode referenciar a Application.
Mas eu quero que todas as camadas tenham acesso ao serviço de log.

- Existe algum padrão para resolver isso?
- E como fazer com a camada de Domínio que não pode referênciar
  ninguém?

Comment: Por que a camada de Application tem a interface? O certo seria isso ficar em Domain.

Comment: Oi Cigano, é porque, pelo que entendi, a application é responsável por coordenar o projeto, como por exemplo: saber quando chamar as operações de banco, saber quando enviar um email, chamar uma regra de negócio, etc. Mas então nesse caso o domínio é quem deve criar a interface? Porque pelo que entendi também, o domínio deve ficar responsável somente pelas regras de negócio.

Comment: Cria na camada de CrossCutting (dentro da Infra)... Você pode centralizar uma Library só contento lógica de Logs (tanto pra sua Application quanto pra outras camadas se desejar)... Eu faço assim.

Comment: Aqui que começam os infinitos problemas da abordagem DDD em cima de MVC. Repare que, sem usar toda essa estratificação, que não deixa seu projeto melhor, é possível [implementar de maneira muito mais simples um sistema de log usando ActionFilters](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21511/como-implementar-um-log-de-atualiza%c3%a7%c3%b5es-com-asp-net-mvc). Mas te respondendo, sim, a interface fica em Domain, porque Domain não modela apenas o domínio e as regras de negócio, como também detém o ponto de partida do sistema todo.

Comment: Arquitetura serve ao seu propósito enquanto programador, e não o contrário; conforme o Cigano disse, talvez fosse melhor implementar o simples. Implementado o simples, talvez(sim, talvez) você implemente algo mais sofisticado. Log, conforme Wilson comentou, me parece algo de "preocupações ortogonais", ou seja, teoricamente deveria cobrir toda a aplicação.

Comment: Melhor conceito para o seu cenário é o de cross-cutting ("transversal"). Melhores informações: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82976/oque-%C3%A9-cross-cutting-e-qual-sua-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-aspect-oriented-programming-aop