# Uso de Classe.apply no contexto de classe especializada

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Vi um exemplo que tratava de Classe pai e Classe filha onde, no início da classe especializada, estava assim:

```
var ClasseFilha = function ClasseFilha (){
    ClassePai.apply(this, arguments);

    ...
};
```

Embora entenda como funciona o `apply` e veja como a classe filha se modifica na passagem pela segunda linha (usar this antes e depois do `apply` trazem resultados diferentes), fico confuso como o `ClassePai.apply(`) modifique a `ClasseFilha` sem uma atribuição direta em uma variável, por exemplo.

Gostaria de uma explicação mais teórica pra isso, se possível.

Comment: Sobre a dúvida, se você tem familiaridade com OOP, isso equivale a uma chamada `super()`.

Comment: Sim, isso eu compreendo. Não compreendo como a chamada funciona dentro da logica da engine do JS. Como o apply modifica o this? Como o this no contexto da classe filha herda os métodos da classe pai depois da passagem da linha dois? Essa é uma das características do apply?

Comment: O bfavaretto explicou ainda melhor que eu. Se tiveres duvidas pergunta/comenta. Se ficou resolvido acho a resposta dele mais completa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resumidamente, esse `apply` vai executar o construtor da classe pai no contexto da classe filha. É isso que ele faz, chama uma função forçando um valor para `this` dentro dela. Ou seja, qualquer referência a `this` no construtor `ClassePai` vai estar se referindo ao `this` que acabou de ser criado na execução de `new ClasseFilha(...)`.

Você disse:

> fico confuso como o `ClassePai.apply()` modifique a `ClasseFilha` sem uma atribuição direta em uma variável

Na verdade você não está modificando `ClasseFilha` (que é um construtor), e sim um objeto que está sendo instanciado com `new ClasseFilha()`. E não necessariamente você está modificando, depende do que o construtor `ClassePai` faz. Se você tem familiaridade com OOP, a linha do `apply` equivale a uma chamada de `super()` em linguagens que implementam OOP baseado em classes ([JS é baseado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%C3%B3tipos-em-javascript/15247#15247) [em protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42962/o-que-%C3%A9-prot%C3%B3tipo-javascript/42968#42968)).

Você comentou:

> Como o apply modifica o this?

O `this` em si (a referência) não é modificado. O objeto para que ele aponta – que acabou de ser criado com `new ClasseFilha()` – é que pode ser alterado pela função  `ClassePai`. Isso vai depender do código dessa função. E vai depender do contexto onde o trecho de código que você postou está inserido. O que leva à sua próxima dúvida:

> Como o this no contexto da classe filha herda os métodos da classe pai depois da passagem da linha dois? Essa é uma das características do apply?

Esse tipo de construção costuma vir num contexto assim:

```
var ClassePai = function ClassePai(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
};

var ClasseFilha = function ClasseFilha (){
    ClassePai.apply(this, arguments);
};

var filho = new ClasseFilha('nome do filho');
```

Neste caso, o objeto `filho` vai ganhar uma propriedade `nome` que é "injetada" nele pelo construtor do pai. A chamada do `apply` só garante a execução do construtor da superclasse. Os métodos dela não estão disponíveis. Se o construtor `ClassePai` tentar executar um método que conste do seu protótipo, vai dar erro, porque nesse código a classe filha não herda o protótipo do pai. Mas é possível fazer herdar, assim:

```js
var ClassePai = function ClassePai(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.ola();
};

ClassePai.prototype = {
    ola: function() {
        console.log('Olá, meu nome é ' + this.nome);
    }
};

var ClasseFilha = function ClasseFilha (){
    ClassePai.apply(this, arguments);
};

// Sem a linha abaixo, o construtor do pai
// daria erro na chamada a this.ola.
// Esta linha é que arma a herança entre as classes
// (coloca as duas na mesma cadeia de protótipos)
ClasseFilha.prototype = Object.create(ClassePai.prototype);

var filho = new ClasseFilha('nome do filho');
```

Comment: Não sei se estou sendo claro, se não estiver pergunte aqui nos comentários.

Comment: Excelente, entendi perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Quando "emprestas" o `this` via `ClassePai.apply(this, arguments);` permites a `ClassePai` de modificar o `this` que pertence à `ClasseFilha`. Isso permite extender a classe se o código assim quiser.

Um exemplo:

```js
function ClassePai(nome, idade) {
  this.nome = nome;
  this.idade = idade;
  this.dizerNome = function() {
    console.log(this.nome);
  }
}

var ClasseFilha = function ClasseFilha() {
  ClassePai.apply(this, arguments);
  this.naturalidade = arguments[2];
  this.naturalDe = function(){
    console.log(this.naturalidade);
  }
};

var pessoaA = new ClasseFilha('Pedro', 34, 'Portugal');
var pessoaB = new ClasseFilha('Ana', 34, 'Brazil');

pessoaA.dizerNome();
pessoaB.dizerNome();
pessoaB.naturalDe();
```

De resto a [explicação do @bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212845/129) está bem completa

Comment: @Brunno note que no exemplo do Sergio a classe filha não herda nada da classe pai. O método `dizerNome` não está no protótipo do pai, cada instância criada vai ganhar sua própria cópia desse método. (Sergio, tentei achar pergunta sobre isso aqui no site mas não encontrei; não é possível, deve ter alguma).

Comment: @bfavaretto também não encontro. O mais próximo é [o conceito de mixin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27179/129)  que neste caso até se aplica.

Comment: Sergio, só escolhi a resposta do bfavaretto por estar mais esmiuçada, mas também agradeço sua disposição em ajudar.

Comment: @BrunnoVianna fizeste muito bem! Ele costuma ser melhor a explicar que eu :)